# wp_footer() doesn't work without wp_head()?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'am using simple ajax method to load content in wordpress site: i catch clicks on navigation links and add GET parameter to url:

```
jQuery('#topnav a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'GET', 
     url: url,
     data: 'naked=1', // my parameter
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(data){
                jQuery('#content').html(data); // load new content
            });     
        }       
    });
});
```

after i check this parameter in templates of wordpress and if this parameter exists i do not include header and footer and load naked content:

```
<?php
/**
* page.php
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage clean
*/
if (!isset($_GET['naked'])) get_header(); // if parameter exist do not load header ?> 
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); // cycle wp start ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; // cycle wp end
if (!isset($_GET['naked'])) get_footer(); // if parameter exist do not load footer ?>
```

This method worked fine, but if page contain contactform7 shortcode, ajax submiting form doesn't work because footer.php not includes js staff for form.

I tried to put wp_footer() function into page.php, but **function not adding js scripts for form!** If i put wp_head() in page.php too - wp_footer() works fine.

Any ideas please.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Wordpress, belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Raptor And yet, it has three upvotes. I'm all for keeping questions "on topic." But this is no worse than most of the other 63,000 WordPress posts on SO.

Comment: They should be ALL migrated to the mentioned sites. Just a matter of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look on [line 200 of wp-includes/default-filters.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/213ecc8a07fc0ae7f1113187eb839170568c4f84/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L200), you'll notice that scripts are enqueued with `wp_head`.

This is why your scripts aren't working. `wp_head()` is a critical function for Contact Form 7 to function properly. You need to still include `wp_head()`, but don't need to include `wp_header()` in order for that to happen. For example, the following should keep things "naked", but still allow scripts to be loaded:

```
if ( !isset($_GET['naked']) ) {
    get_header(); // if parameter exist do not load header
} else {
    wp_head(); // still include wp_head(), but without the rest of the "header"
}
```

Make sure that `wp_head()` is still run within your document `<head></head>` section.